# Stack-based buffer overflow - challenge in C using scanf with limited input

Tags: c, md5, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow, stack-smash

As part of a security CS course, my class has been given the task of exploiting a vulnerability to beat a password check using a stack/buffer overflow. The code with the vulnerability is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char correct_hash[16] = {
        0xd0, 0xf9, 0x19, 0x94, 0x4a, 0xf3, 0x10, 0x92,
        0x32, 0x98, 0x11, 0x8c, 0x33, 0x27, 0x91, 0xeb
    };
    char password[16];

    printf("Insert your password: ");
    scanf("%29s", password);

    MD5(password, strlen(password), password);

    if (memcmp(password, correct_hash, 16) == 0) {
        printf("Correct Password!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Wrong Password, sorry!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I understand the classic "stack-smashing" principle (I think), and there is a clear overflow vulnerability here, where the first 14 bytes of the `correct_hash` array can be overwritten, by inputting a password longer than 15 characters when prompted. However, I don't understand how to leverage this to allow the `memcmp` check to pass, completing the challenge. Some of the things I have discovered/attempted:

- Setting `password` to be the equivalent of `correct_hash` doesn't work, as `password` gets hashed using `MD5()` (setting the two to be equal is impossible anyway, as `scanf` will insert precisely one unique ASCII `NUL` character into the 30 spaces available to it, meaning the two arrays can never be equivalent. `NUL` characters additionally (to my knowledge) cannot be inserted in the middle of a `scanf` string).
- Overwriting the maximum number of bytes with `scanf` (which will always append a `NUL` character) means the last 3 bytes of `correct_hash` will always be `0x00 0x91 0xeb`. Attempting to randomly generate a 16-character password that then hashes to something with these last 3 bytes/characters (reasonably computationally easy, given the use of MD5) doesn't work, however, due to the use of `strlen(password)` (which will give a value of **29** instead of something convenient like 16 thanks to only finishing the length count upon hitting a `NUL` character) in the call to `MD5()`. This means that instead of hashing the 16-character password to produce the expected output, the call to `MD5()` will hash 16 characters from `password` followed by 13 characters from `correct_hash`, producing a different final hashed value.

  - To get around this problem, I believe one would have to find a 29-character string (call it S) where the first 16 characters of S hash to a string R comprised of the last 13 characters of S, followed by `0x00 0x91 0xeb`. I'm not sure how viable finding this through random MD5 hash computation is, but it don't fancy my chances.

Some notes (mentioned in the explanations above):

- `scanf` is limited to a 29 character string, but will append an ASCII `NUL` character, allowing 30 characters total (16 from the `password` array, 14 from the `correct_hash` array) to be overwritten.
- ASCII `NUL` characters cannot be input via `scanf` so the `strlen(password)` in the call to `MD5()` (if the maximum password length is used) will be 29.

**So the question here is, how else could I go about doing this? Am I missing something extremely obvious? Is random generation a viable solution, or even the only solution?**

The solution has to use a buffer overflow (otherwise I imagine I could do something like preload a `memcmp` that always returns 0), and has to be executable as a shell script (if that's of any relevance).

Comment: The crux of the matter is, that scanf will happily accept a zero-byte as part of a string and will _not_ treat it as whitespace (thus, will not stop reading further bytes into the string). With this information, your task should be easy.

Comment: `char password[16]; ... scanf("%29s", password);` is not exploiting a vulnerablity. It's deliberately creating one.

Comment: @Ctx: that's true but entering `NUL` bytes from the terminal is not easy.

Comment: @chqrlie Seriously? Redirect a file or use `echo -ne "\x00" | program` or the like

Comment: @Ctx Interesting - I couldn't get it do so, but I was providing input via bash, using some backtick-quoted perl code. In this instance it seemed to completely ignore any null characters I had inserted.

Comment: @WeatherVane The purpose of this exercise was to learn about these types of vulnerabilities (presumably without it being too easy, as a straight `scanf` with no limitations would have been), to better prevent them or spot them in the wild. I'll admit, it looks a little strange. A potential premise here: modified code, where the password array was shortened from 30 to 16 characters?

Comment: @B.Martin it is a pity you cannot use a `*` followed by a size argument as you can in `printf()`. In `scanf()` it has a different meaning. I suggest more robust code would use `fgets` with a `sizeof` argument that would follow any change to `password[]` length.

Comment: @B.Martin Redirecting an input file is probably the preferred way here. Did it work now?

Comment: @Ctx Yes, that seems to have done it! Thanks a lot. The final command I used was: `echo -ne "\x49\x5a\x4e\x52\x48\x49\x41\x56\x5a\x43\x54\x52\x51\x4c\x43\x00\x81\xae\xf3\xdf\xa2\x45\xb1\x57\x19\xb3\xa9\xb8\x7d\x00\x91\xeb" | ./vulnerable` where the first set of 16 bytes (up to and including the first `\x00`) were a randomly generated string, which, when hashed produced the second set of 16 bytes, with the required `\x00\x91\xeb` ending. The last 3 bytes there weren't copied anyway, but I left them in to show the string and hash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to merge the comments into an answer here:

The crux of the matter is, that `scanf` will happily accept a zero-byte as part of a string and will not treat it as whitespace (thus, will not stop reading further bytes into the string).

Redirect a file or use `echo -ne "\x00" | program` or the like. Redirecting an input file is probably the preferred way here.

The final command I used was: `echo -ne "\x49\x5a\x4e\x52\x48\x49\x41\x56\x5a\x43\x54\x52\x51\x4c\x4‌​3\x00\x81\xae\xf3\xd‌​f\xa2\x45\xb1\x57\x1‌​9\xb3\xa9\xb8\x7d\x0‌​0\x91\xeb" | ./vulnerable` where the first set of 16 bytes (up to and including the first `\x00`) were a randomly generated string, which, when hashed produced the second set of 16 bytes, with the required `\x00\x91\xeb` ending. The last 3 bytes there weren't copied anyway, but I left them in to show the string and hash.